# Net Maui - The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found

Tags: .net, maui, .net-maui

I am using .NET Maui and suddenly got an error with the error code CS0246 in the File MauiProgram.cs. The code of the file is:

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        Builder
            . UseMauiApp<App>()
            . ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                Fonts. AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                Fonts. AddFont("OpenSans Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

return builder. Build();
    }
}
```

The error is displayed as following:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   itsl (net6.0-maccatalyst), itsl (net6.0-windows10.0.22621.0)    A:\VS\itsl\itsl\MauiProgram.cs  9   Active

I've already cleaned up the solution and restarted Visual Studio, but unfortunately nothing helped.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`App` is the class defined in `App.xaml`.  By default it should be in the same namespace as `MauiProgram`, but if you have manually changed a namespace you may need to add a `using` statement